# Setting divider programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to set the divider in my TableLayout/TableRow programmatically because I make the UI on the go. The code I am using is as follows:

```
    ...
    tablelayout.setDividerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.attr.dividerHorizontal));
    tablelayout.setDividerPadding(4);
    ...
```

I am trying to replicate the following code:

```
<...>
     ...
     android:showDividers="middle"
     android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
     android:dividerPadding="8dp"
     ...>
</...>
```

Here is my log:

```
08-29 01:49:09.880: W/ResourceType(1714): Requesting resource 0x101030a failed because it is complex
08-29 01:49:09.885: W/System.err(1714): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x101030a
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1025)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:670)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at com.tabcards.android.Search.createUI(Search.java:178)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at com.tabcards.android.Search.access$2(Search.java:142)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at com.tabcards.android.Search$1$1.run(Search.java:128)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 01:49:09.900: W/System.err(1714):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
08-29 01:49:09.905: W/System.err(1714):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit:
I have looked at the source code of [attr.xml](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/881586ca84f2fb8e82faa9c8d645416d175d0f01/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml) and I have found the following line:

```
...
<attr name="dividerVertical" format="reference"/>
...
```

Comment: I notice that you are using the name **dividerVertical** in the attr.xml and the code you're trying to replicate, but in your code example you use **dividerHorizontal**. Are you sure you're attempting to get the correct resource?

Comment: @NathanNorman Yes, I noticed that too... Silly of me. Anyway, I solved my problem.

Comment: What ended up solving the problem?

Comment: @NathanNorman I used a custom divider (one made in `style.xml` and then adding it to a view with a width of 1 px)

Answer (score 0):

If using Eclipse, delete r.java file. It will be remade automatically. Then go to Project -> Clean. Then try running again.

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything.